# How can update data using time date now

Tags: laravel

I have table users like this:

```
id ,name , dob , tempo_date , etc ... . .. . .
```

and i want to update data this tempo_date .

this type data tempo_date is **date** like : **2019-07-25**

i want to make function on controller , if tempo_date = date now (today) , its will + 2 years . from **2019-07-25** to **2021-07-25**

```
public function input_pelatihan()
{
    $users = DB::table('users');

    $now = Carbon::now();
    $add = // i dont know what to do here

    return view('admin.input',
    [
    'users'=>$users,


    ]);
}
```

someone can help me , i dont know what to do

Comment: reading and understanding this will help you
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just code simple like below :

```
if($tempo_date->equalTo(now())) {
  $tempo_date = now()->addYears(2)
}
```

Comment: before this i need declare this $tempo_date . its like $tempo_date = User->tempo_date->get(); . like this ?

Comment: You can get $tempo_date of current login user like this : `$tempo_date = \Auth::user()->tempo_date;` if you have `tempo_date` column in `users` table

Comment: how about if iam using another table ? like roles . its cannot using Auth::user

Comment: You should have relationship with `users` table, then you can call to `tempo_date` like this : `\Auth::user()->roles->tempo_date` with `roles` is your relationship name. Or you can call direct to `roles` table like : `Roles::findOrFail($role_id)->tempo_date;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood of your description, what you are trying to do is have a date two years from now. You can do so by using a helper and applying carbon methods to it: `now()->addYears(2)`.

Comment: how about this if else condition ? if tempo_date = $now , its will add 2 years ?